# SMTP SendEmail hung without any error our response

Tags: c#, smtp

I am using SmtpClient to send email with attachment. The send email method is below

```
  public static void SendEmail(string subject, string messageBody, string toEmailId, List<string> attachments=null, List<string> cc = null, bool IsBodyHtml = false)
    {
        try
        {

            var fromAddress = new MailAddress("email@email.com");
            var toAddress = new MailAddress(toEmailId);
            const string fromPassword = "password";


            var smtp = new SmtpClient
            {
                Host = "smtp.gmail.com",
                Port = 587,
                EnableSsl = true,
                DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network,
                UseDefaultCredentials = false,
                Credentials = new NetworkCredential(fromAddress.Address, fromPassword),
                Timeout= 1000 * 60
            };


            using (var message = new MailMessage(fromAddress, toAddress)
            {

                Subject = subject,
                Body = messageBody,
                IsBodyHtml = IsBodyHtml


            })
            {
                if (cc != null)
                {
                    foreach (string s in cc)
                        message.CC.Add(s);
                }

                if (attachments != null)
                {
                    foreach (string attachment in attachments)
                    {
                        message.Attachments.Add(new Attachment(attachment));

                    }
                }



                Console.WriteLine("email sending");
                smtp.Send(message);

                //Clean up attachments
                foreach (Attachment attachment in message.Attachments)
                {
                    attachment.Dispose();
                }

            }

        }

        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }

    }
```

I am able to send the email without attachment with the above SMTP config. But when I use attachment the program hangs after `smtp.Send(message)` without giving any response/error.

The same code runs fine on my local machine but when I upload it to server and run it dont' response. I have also tried the following steps on server.

1. Opened port 587 on server.
2. Gave all permission to the attachment folder.

Comment: Maybe it's the size of your attachment and you just have to wait a bit longer?

Comment: Size is around "1MB". I also tested it with lesser size file. This is a console program and code doesn't move after "smtp.send(message)" line.

Comment: Can you show how you load the attachment?

Comment: Any chance your attachments are being modified while you try and send them?

Comment: No.. I also tried to upload from a fresh folder. The problem here is that I am not getting any error..Console just showing my message "Sending Email..." before the "sendemail" method.

Comment: Try and catch all first chance exceptions in visual studio

Comment: Actually I can debug the code on my local machine and its working fine there. But I cant debug it on server. On server I have to run direct exe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is firewall installed on the server and it was blocking the emails with attachment of size more than 1 MB. Also it was blocking some SMTP connections.